# How can I select and display the maximum (and minimum) values from among several fields in a single record in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table which lists several tours and for each tour there are several categories of accommodation types with different prices, along with a lot of other fields such as dates, deadlines etc.  It was easy to set things up to display the array showing the tour, dates, deadlines but I also want to select and display the maximum (and minimum when not 0) accommodation rates for each tour. I may not be understanding some of the answers I'm seeing but most seem to be looking for max values within a field rather than across fields. I'm assuming once I know how to find the max value, finding the min value would be the same basic procedure.

the abbreviated table structure with example data is:

```
id   tourID    RmA    RmB   RmC   RmD ...other fields...
1      mb      600    450   550   300
2      kr      900      0   600   450
3      ww      500    650   550   600
4      wf      750    300   400   500
```

What I'd like to add to my current display is:

```
Tour     Rates
 mb    300 - 600 
 kr    450 - 900
 WW    500 - 650
 wf    300 - 750
```

I apologise if I'm repeating a frequently asked question, but it may be that I haven't googled my question in a manner to find the appropriate answer.

Comment: Thank you Dave for editing my entry to make it readable.  I'm guessing that I should have known how to do that.  Mihai and Wolf, the greatest/least coding works like a charm, BUT is there any way to get LEAST to ignore 0 or null values?  Not all tours have all room options available so there are many zero or null values in the data set.

Comment: A, B, C, & D all seem to be the same sort of thing. If so, consider normalizing your table. Remember, a table is NOT a spreadsheet.

Comment: Mihai, it's ugly, but it works.  I can't thank you enough!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `LEAST()` and `GREATEST()` ([docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest))

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Tour,GROUP_CONCAT(LEAST(RmA,RmB,RmC,RmD),GREATEST(RmA,RmB,RmC,RmD) SEPARATOR'-') as Rates FROM table
```

You just use least and greatest to get the maximum and respective minimum value from all 4 columns and then you add them together with group_concat.

```
    SELECT Tour,GROUP_CONCAT(LEAST(
COALESCE(NULLIF(RmA,0),NULLIF(RmB,0),NULLIF(RmC,0),NULLIF(RmD,0)),
COALESCE(NULLIF(RmB,0),NULLIF(RmC,0),NULLIF(RmD,0),NULLIF(RmA,0)),
COALESCE(NULLIF(RmC,0),NULLIF(RmD,0),NULLIF(RmA,0),NULLIF(RmB,0)),
COALESCE(NULLIF(RmD,0),NULLIF(RmA,0),NULLIF(RmB,0),NULLIF(RmC,0)))
    ,GREATEST(RmA,RmB,RmC,RmD) SEPARATOR'-') as Rates FROM table
```

Comment: This answer was flagged and I'm not sure how to vote. Please improve it a bit, add some more explanation.

Comment: Huh?why it was flagged?

Comment: Not sure why do you expect me to read the mind of someone who flagged it, but I've given you my guess on this - consider adding some more explanation.

Comment: You should consider also some malicious flag because people have nothing better to do.Bullshit flagging is not punished?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Also, maybe it was a mistake. However note, that I don't consider myself an SQL expert so it was hard for me to decide if it's just some random SQL, or really an answer. That's why I wrote a comment here. Thanks for the update, now the answer looks really better and may be more helpful for others!